# How to dynamically select tables and columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I am trying to create a `SQL code` in `SQL Server` that dynamically selects all the tables in a specific database and then for each column in each table, counts the number of missing values and non-null values. I also want this result inserted into another table.

Is there any way I can do this without manually changing the column names for each:

`Table Name - Column selection`

I have a teradata code for the same which I tried to convert to `SQL Server code`. But I am unable to get the dynamic allocation and insertion parts right.

```
insert into temp
values (select  ''CAMP'',
    rtrim(''' || tablename || '''),
    rtrim(''' || columnname || '''),
    rtrim(''' || columnformat || '''),
    count(1),
    count(rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end))),
    (cast (count(rtrim(upper(case when  ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else  ' || columnname || ' end))) as float) / (cast (count(1) as float))) * 100,
    count(distinct rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end))),
    min(rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end))),
    max(rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end))),
    min(len(rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end)))),
    max(len(rtrim(upper(case when ' || columnname || '='''' then NULL else '|| columnname ||' end))))
from    ' || tablename ||')
```

Any help on this front would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: I edited the question to include what I tried. Any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of selecting data from different table and inserting them in another table, you can try view in SQL for this.

Comment: I am trying to use this to create a view of all the existing tables and some basic information about them. This will help me get an understanding of the kind of data I have in all my tables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need a `UNION` or a `JOIN`, but in either case you can just use a three-part name for the object in the other database if you are using multi-database:

```
USE database1; // Your database name
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
    SELECT columns FROM dbo.Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT columns FROM database2.dbo.Table2; //second database
GO

select * from dbo.MyView // Getting all data from view
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help you:

```
    SELECT  [Table] = t.[name]
        , [Column] = c.[name]
    FROM    sys.tables t
    INNER   JOIN    sys.columns c
        ON  c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
```